# Where can i find sample alogrithms for analyzing historical stock prices?

Tags: algorithm, stocks

Can anyone direct me in the right direction?

Basically, I'm trying to analyze stock prices and see if I can spot any patterns. I'm using PHP and MySQL to do this. Where can I find sample algorithms like the ones used in MetaStock or thinkorswim? I know they are closed source, but are there any tutorials available for beginners?

Thank you,

P.S. I don't even know what to search for in google :(

Comment: Search for "technical analysis".

Comment: A common thing to do is to use various Artificial Intelligence algorithms to extract patterns. The NetFlix challenge has **a lot** of examples with practical AI and statistical algorithms.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A basic, educational algorithm to start with is a dual-crossover [moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average). Simply chart fast (say, 5-day) and slow (say, 10-day) moving averages of a stock's closing price, and you have a weak predictor of when to buy long (fast line goes above slow) and sell short (slow line goes above the fast). After getting this working, you could implement exponential smoothing (see previously linked wiki article).

That would be a decent start. Take a look at other [technical analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_analysis) techniques, but do keep in mind that this is quite a perilous method of trading.

Update: As for actually implementing this? You're a PHP programmer, so here is a [charting library for PHP](http://jpgraph.net). This is the one I used a few years ago for this very project, and it worked out swimmingly. Maybe someone else can recommend a better one. If you need a free source of data, take a look at [Yahoo! Finance's historical data](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=GOOG). They dispense CSV files containing daily opening prices, closing prices, trading volume, etc. of virtually every indexed corporation.

Comment: Technical analysis is what you want. Also see http://www.riskglossary.com/ for help while trying to make sense of this.

Comment: yeah, i know it is technical analysis that i want, but my question was how do i program those that patterns? of course I could make my own algorithm but since i don't have experience it would not be an efficient one.

Answer (score 3):

First you will need a solid math background : statistics in general, correlation analysis, linear algebra... If you really want to push it check out dimensional transposition.  Then you will need solid basis in [Data Mining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mining).  [Associations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rules) can be useful if yo want to link strict numerical data with news headlines and other events.

One thing for sure you will most likely not find pre-digested algorithms out there that will make you rich...

I know someone who is trying just that...  He is somewhat successful (meaning is is not loosing money and is making a bit)  and making his own algorithms...   I should mention he has a doctorate in [Actuarial science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actuarial).

Here are a few more links... hope they help out a bit

- http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ActuarialScience.html
- http://www.actuary.com/actuarial-science/
- http://www.actuary.ca/

Best of luck to you

Answer (score 3):

Check out algorithms at [investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com) and [FM Labs](http://www.fmlabs.com/reference/) has formulas for a lot of technical analysis indicators.

Comment: thank you, but i was more interested in how to program and find patterns, which is, I'm guessing, is more than just implementing technical indicator formulas

Comment: Okay, then here is an article I wrote that takes a technical analysis formula and works through producing code: http://www.iwebthereforeiam.com/iwebthereforeiam/2008/05/money-flow-index-and-other-tec.html

Answer (score 3):

Save yourself time and use programs like [NinjaTrader](http://www.NinjaTrader.com/) and [Wealth-Lab](http://www.Wealth-Lab.com/). Both of them are great technical analysis platforms and accept C# as a programming language for defining your trading rules. Every possible technical indicator you can imagine is already included and if you need something more advanced you can always write your own indicator. You would also need a lot of data in order for your analysis to be statistically significant. For US stocks and ETFs, visit [www.Kibot.com](http://www.kibot.com/). We have good experience using their data.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pattern for ya
http://ddshankar.files.wordpress.com/2008/02/image001.jpg

Comment: beautiful :) (no, it doesn't need 15 chars)

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with a good [introduction to](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/5386.html) [time series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series) analysis and go from there. If you're interested in finding patterns then the interesting term is "1D-Pattern Matching". But for that you need nice features, so google for ["Feature extraction in time series"](http://www.google.com/search?q=feature+extraction+in+time+series&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a). Remember [GiGo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_In,_Garbage_Out). So make sure you have error-free stock price data for a sufficiently long timeperiod before you start.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest that you do a little reading with respect to the Kalman filter?  Wikipedia is a pretty good place to start:
    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter/

This should give you a little background on the problem of estimating and predicting the variables of some system (the stock market in this case).

But the stock market is not very well behaved so you may want to familiarize yourself with non linear extensions to the KF.  Yes, the wikipedia entry has sections on the extended KF and the unscented KF, but here is an introduction that is just a little more in-depth:
    http://cslu.cse.ogi.edu/nsel/ukf/

I suppose if anyone had ever tried this before then it would have been all over the news and very well known.  So you may very well be on to something.

Answer (score 0):

Use [TradeStation](http://www.tradestation.com)

It is a platform that lets you write software to analyze historical stock data. You can even write programs that would trade the stock, and you can back test your program on historical data or run it real time through out the day.